# Regex: find last occurrence of pattern

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

I am trying to find a regular expression that will match the last occurrence of a specific language tag with no other language tags found afterwards.

- specific language tag: `_en`
- language tag: `_[a-z]{2}`

For example, the pattern **should** match all of the following:

```
title_en
components_en.video.title
components_en.video.title_en
components_en.video.the_end
components_es.video.title_en
```

Also, the pattern **should not** match any of the following:

```
title_es
components_es.video.title
components_en.video.title_es
components_es.video.the_end
```

Comment: What is your flavor?(language you are using)

Comment: elasticsearch (java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
_en(\.|$)(?!.*_[a-z]{2}(\.|$))
```

Here's [a fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/U5K7LT/2) showing how it performs on your test cases.

If you want to match the entire string, prefix the expression with `^.*` and suffix with `.*$`.

```
^.*_en(\.|$)(?!.*_[a-z]{2}(\.|$)).*$
```

Results are shown in [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/U5K7LT/3).

Comment: is there any way to match the entire string with this?

Comment: @clud Beat you to it :) Updated my answer.

Comment: What's the dot (`\.`) good for? This doesn't match `…end` as intended.

Comment: @Bergi `_end` does not need to be matched. The `_en` before `_end` needs to be matched however.